# clear/finish all activities including SingleInstance activities from the stack in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities namely A, B, and C.  A is launcher activity while B and C are singleInstance activities. The sequence of movement between activities I want is A(press button) -> B  and then B <-> C (i.e, B and C keeps alternating as many times as they want). When in B, pressing navigation up button takes me to activity A.

Now the problem arises. I am in A now and want to go to B(by pressing button) like I did during start of my App(i.e, I want it to work as if the app has been launched). But it tries to go to activity B and suddenly with a flash it returns back to A. The funny part now is that when I try again(i.e in activity A I press the button again) it goes to B without any problem and the flow works as expected i.e, the flow of activities are same as it was on launch time.

**What I want finally?**

Once I reach launcher activity which is activity A, I want the app to behave as if it was just launched. i.e all activity including singleInstance activities should be cleared from the stack.

I have tried this in `onSupportNavigationUp()` method in activity B:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
        mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        B.this.finish();
```

I even tried adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` also.

But this doesn't help. The problem remains unsolved.

Any kind of suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain why B and C need to be `singleInstance`. This is not normal and will confuse users and you probably don't need this.

Comment: Also, this is probably what is causing the bad behaviour you mention.

Comment: @David, I am downloading some data when in B and when in C i go back to B through an intent and I don't want it to download data again but use existing data. If I am going the wrong way, please guide me the right way. Thank you!

Comment: You do not need `singleInstance` to do this. When you return from C to B via `Intent` just add an "extra" to the `Intent` that indicates you are returning from C. Either that or remember that you've downloaded data in an instance variable. Or use `startActivityForResult()`. There are many ways to do this. You definitely don't need the special launch mode.

Comment: If this isn't enough help, please show more code and give some examples of what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try the solutions.